# Show a button if there is data in SQL and hide otherwise

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql

I am new and practising. So, I am sure I am not doing this the best way possible.

I am trying to get the product data to show if there is data, but if there isn't any data, I want the button to be hidden. In the DB, only about 40% actually have product data.

```php
foreach ($part->results as $index=>$row){

echo '<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> Add to Cart</a>
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> Info
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="btn btn-info " href="./media/products/product_data/'.$row["product_data"].'" target="_blank"class="btn btn-info"> Details </a>

</div>'
```

Comment: you really need to add more to be able to answer this - the query would be useful otherwise perhaps simply `if( !empty($part->results) ){/* do the loop */}`

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS and classes to show / hide elements on the page.
In the css:

```
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

Then you can echo this via php:

```
foreach ($part->results as $index=>$row){
    $hidden = empty($row["product_data"]) ? ' hidden' : ''; //determine if hidden needs to be added or not

    echo '<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> Add to Cart</a>
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button' . $hidden . '" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> Info
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="btn btn-info " href="./media/products/product_data/'.$row["product_data"].'" target="_blank"class="btn btn-info"> Details </a>

</div>'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function.  I cleaned your code a bit, but it would look something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($part->results as $index=>$row) : ?>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Info</button>
    </div>
    <?php if (!empty($row["product_data"])): ?>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="btn btn-info " href="./media/products/product_data/>
           <?= $row["product_data"]; ?>" target="_blank"class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
      </div>;
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This would not output the `<div class="dropdown-menu">` section for any that were missing product-data.  You could move the if-condition somewhere else to omit other output.

If you want to skip the whole row, use [continue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) in your existing code:

```
foreach ($part->results as $index=>$row){

// this will skip the loop whenever product-data is missing
if(empty($row["product_data"]))
   continue;

echo '<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> Add to Cart</a>
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> Info
</button>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="btn btn-info " href="./media/products/product_data/'.$row["product_data"].'" target="_blank"class="btn btn-info"> Details </a>

</div>'
?>
```

If you still want output and then hide it with CSS, @JackofSpades has the right answer.